# Why can't we keep the hats after Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

It would be great if the hats could be kept and worn after Winter Bash. Why can't the hats be kept for the year until the next Winter Bash?

Furthermore, the design of the hats fit all seasons, not just suitable for winter, though it's serves a greater purpose during winter since it's cold ;)

Comment: Because the FAQ says "No" ;p

Comment: That'd be like asking for an advent calendar that covers 365 days of the year. It's not special if you have it all the time!

Comment: A bash for each season with different accessories would be cool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hats are not intended to be permanent.

You can, of course, take screenshots of your avatar wearing your favourite hat(s) and use those as your profile image after January 8th.

> **What happens after January 8th?**
>
> After January 8th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear.
>   This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent
>   addition to the site.

Source [FAQ](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: That's why hats get much more attention then badges.